# "=~" raise "No instance for (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])"

Tags: regex, haskell

OS: MacOSX 10.7.1
GHC and Haskell-platform from brew.

```
   GHCi, version 7.0.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
    Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
    Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
    Loading package base ... linking ... done.
    Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
    Prelude> :m +Text.Regex.Posix
    Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "foo" =~ "o" :: [String]

    <interactive>:1:7:
        No instance for (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])
          arising from a use of `=~'
        Possible fix:
          add an instance declaration for
          (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])
        In the expression: "foo" =~ "o" :: [String]
        In an equation for `it': it = "foo" =~ "o" :: [String]
    Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "foo" =~ "o" :: String
    Loading package array-0.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
    Loading package bytestring-0.9.1.10 ... linking ... done.
    Loading package containers-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
    Loading package transformers-0.2.2.0 ... linking ... done.
    Loading package mtl-2.0.1.0 ... linking ... done.
    Loading package regex-base-0.93.2 ... linking ... done.
    Loading package regex-posix-0.95.1 ... linking ... done.
    "o"
```

I believe libraries updated. And I think the output of `"foo" =~ "o" :: [String]` is `["o", "o"]`

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ghci> getAllTextMatches ("foo" =~ "o" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
["o", "o"]
```

I haven't used regexes in Haskell much (which is I think [Dan Burton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636447/raise-no-instance-for-regexcontext-regex-char-string/7637354#7637354) is more idiomatic).

So the way I figured this out is I looked at your type error `No instance for (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])`, and popped into ghci:

```
ghci> :t (=~)
(=~)
  :: (RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source,
      RegexContext Regex source1 target) =>
     source1 -> source -> target
```

So `RegexContext Regex [Char] [String]` is a class that includes the return type of `"foo" =~ "o" :: [String]`.  So I looked to see what instances of this class did exist, so I could find out what the return value was allowed to be:

```
ghci> :i RegexContext
class RegexLike
        regex source => RegexContext regex source target where
  match :: regex -> source -> target
  matchM :: Monad m => regex -> source -> m target
        -- Defined in Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
instance RegexContext Regex String String
  -- Defined in Text.Regex.Posix.String
instance RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b [[b]]
  -- Defined in Text.Regex.Base.Context
...
instance RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b (AllTextMatches [] b)
  -- Defined in Text.Regex.Base.Context
...
```

The `AllTextMatches` name seemed to indicate what you were looking for, so I checked that out:

```
ghci> :i AllTextMatches
newtype AllTextMatches f b
  = AllTextMatches {getAllTextMatches :: f b}
        -- Defined in Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike
instance RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b (AllTextMatches [] b)
  -- Defined in Text.Regex.Base.Context
```

So this was the type to use to extract all the text matches, as I suspected.  All I needed to do was indicate that I wanted a return value of that type.

Note also the possible return type of `[[b]]`, which I assume returns a list of lists containing each complete match and all its submatches:

```
ghci> "foo" =~ "o" :: [[String]]
[["o"],["o"]]
ghci> "foo bar baz" =~ "[aeiou](.)" :: [[String]]
[["oo","o"],["ar","r"],["az","z"]]
```

So maybe that's the type you meant to use, instead of `[String]`.  I could see `[String]` as being slightly ambiguous when `[[String]]` existed - should `"foo bar baz" =~ "[aeiou](.)" :: [String]` be `fst ("foo bar baz" =~ "[aeiou](.)" :: [[String]])` or `map fst ("foo bar baz" =~ "[aeiou](.)" :: [[String]])`.

Comment: Thank a lot. I wonder why mine is wrong. I saw that somewhere is correct. Are the libraries too new?

Comment: Pikaurd: I think your code used to work with older versions. I'm not sure, why it was changed, but I prefer the old behavior -- at least at first glance.

Comment: @danlei: Maybe Pikaud meant to use `:: [[String]]`?

Comment: rampion: Cf. Real World Haskell, chapter 8, the regular expression section. ("Another valid type of result is [String], which returns a list of all matching strings.")

Comment: One of the comments (Richard D) indicates, that this might have been a bug fix, but I don't see a problem with the old behavior.

Comment: I like your approach of the problem: analyze the error message and solve the type fiddling interactively in ghci. +1. But in general I'd say the problem is really the (lack) of documentation for such an API change.

Comment: Thank you. Your approach very be enlightening.

Answer (score 9):

This also works

```
ghci> getAllTextMatches $ "foo" =~ "o" :: [String]
["o","o"]
```

Comment: @Pikaurd: Because you didn't use `getAllTextMatches`, basically. Haskell regex stuff is rather complicated to explain; the error message you got says it all, look at the type of `(=~)` and notice the constraints.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> getAllTextMatches ("foo" =~ "o" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
["o","o"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is:

```
map head $ "foo" =~ "o" :: [String]
```

### Explanation

Binding the result of `(=~)` to `[[String]]` will yield a list of matches, in which each match is represented by list of strings.  In each list, its `head` will be the whole match and it's `tail` the matches for each submatches:

```
> "foo goo bar" =~ "(.)o(.)" :: [[String]]
[["foo","f","o"],["goo","g","o"]]

-- Get the second submatch (2) of the first match (0)
> "foo goo bar" =~ "(.)o(.)" !! 0 !! 2 :: String
"o"

-- Get the first submatch (1) of the second match (1)
> "foo goo bar" =~ "(.)o(.)" !! 1 !! 1 :: String
"g"
```

In short, `map head $ string =~ regexp :: [String]` contain the whole matches of `regexp` in `string`.  `map tail $ string =~ regexp :: [[String]]` contain the sub-matches, indicated in the original regexp by encosing parentheses `()`.