# All matches of regex in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell

According to a number of tutorials (including Real World Haskell) one can, using ghci do the following

```
ghci > :m Text.Regex.Posix
ghci > "foo foo foo" =~ "foo" :: [String]
["foo","foo","foo"]
```

Yet, when I attempt this, it yields

```
No instance for (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])
  arising from a use of `=~'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])
In the expression: "abc" =~ "ab" :: [String]
In an equation for `it': it = "abc" =~ "ab" :: [String]
```

What is the correct way of obtaining a list of all matches in haskell?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["=~" raise "No instance for (RegexContext Regex \[Char\] \[String\])"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636447/raise-no-instance-for-regexcontext-regex-char-string)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The regex libraries can be somewhat confusing with their overloaded return types, but to get all the matches you just need to ensure that the return type is `AllTextMatches`, for example:

```
Prelude> :m + Text.Regex.Posix
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> getAllTextMatches $ "foo foo foo" =~ "foo" :: [String]
["foo","foo","foo"]
```

Comment: Well, that works. Thank you. Do you have any idea why this doesn't seem to get mentioned in tutorials?

Comment: @ehird Where could I find an up to date reference?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/erantapaa/haskell-regexp-examples/blob/master/RegexExamples.hs) are valuable examples to sort this out.