# Indices of all matches of a regex

Tags: regex, haskell

I am trying to match all the occurrences of a regex and get the indices as a result. The example from *Real World Haskell* says I can do

```
string =~ regex :: [(Int, Int)]
```

However, this is broken since the regex library has been updated since the publication of RWH. (See [All matches of regex in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049705/all-matches-of-regex-in-haskell) and ["=~" raise "No instance for (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636447/raise-no-instance-for-regexcontext-regex-char-string)). What is the correct way to do this?

**Update:**

I found [matchAll](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base-0.93.2/docs/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v:matchAll) which might give me what I want. I have no idea how to use it, though.

Answer (score 5):

The key to using `matchAll` is using the type annotation `:: Regex` when creating regexs:

```
import Text.Regex
import Text.Regex.Base

re = makeRegex "[^aeiou]" :: Regex
test = matchAll re "the quick brown fox"
```

This returns a list of arrays. To get a list of (offset,length) pairs, just access the first element of each array:

```
import Data.Array ((!))

matches = map (!0) $ matchAll re "the quick brown fox"
-- [(0,1),(1,1),(3,1),(4,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1),(10,1),(11,1),(13,1),(14,1),(15,1),(16,1),(18,1)]
```

To use the `=~` operator, things may have changed since RWH. You should use the predefined types `MatchOffset` and `MatchLength` and the special type constructor `AllMatches`:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix

re = "[^aeiou]"
text = "the quick brown fox"

test1 = text =~ re :: Bool
  -- True

test2 = text =~ re :: String
  -- "t"

test3 = text =~ re :: (MatchOffset,MatchLength)
  -- (0,1)

test4 = text =~ re :: AllMatches [] (MatchOffset, MatchLength)
  -- (not showable)

test4' = getAllMatches $ (text =~ re :: AllMatches [] (MatchOffset, MatchLength))
  -- [(0,1),(1,1),(3,1),(4,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1),(10,1),(11,1),(13,1),(14,1),(15,1),(16,1),(18,1)]
```

See the docs for [Text.Regex.Base.Context](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base-0.93.2/docs/Text-Regex-Base-Context.html) for more details on what contexts are available.

UPDATE: I believe the type constructor `AllMatches` was introduced to resolve the ambiguity introduced when an regex has subexpressions -- e.g.:

```
foo = "axx ayy" =~ "a(.)([^a])"

test1 = getAllMatches $ (foo :: AllMatches [] (MatchOffset, MatchLength))
  -- [(0,3),(3,3)]
  -- returns the locations of "axx" and "ayy" but no subexpression info

test2 = foo :: MatchArray
  -- array (0,2) [(0,(0,3)),(1,(1,1)),(2,(2,1))]
  -- returns only the match with "axx"
```

Both are essentially a list of offset-length pairs, but they mean different things.

Comment: "the typecast :: Regex" is not a type cast. There is no run time modification of the type of the data. It's a type annotation