# Haskell, Regex: reduce a string to a list of matches

Tags: regex, haskell

How am I supposed, say, to create a list of matches:

```
> "aa2gg3tt41u" =~ "\\d+" :: [String]
```

produces an error no matter how I fool with the type annotation. I expect something like `["2","3","41"]`.

Comment: Did you try `[0-9]+`?

Comment: Try with `:: [[String]]` instead of `:: [String]` (depends on the regex library version apparently).

Comment: Related: [*All matches of regex in Haskell*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049705/all-matches-of-regex-in-haskell)

Comment: Which regex library do you use?

Comment: ```*Main Text.Regex.TDFA Text.Regex.Base>```. ```:: [[String]]``` does not produce any error, but I'm getting ```[]``` for a result. Close, but no cigar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `instance RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b [[b]]`:

```
> "aa2gg3tt41u" =~ "[0-9]+" :: [[String]]
[["2"],["3"],["41"]]
```

I hear you say, *"why the `[[String]]`?"* Well, keep in mind that regexes support grouping:

```
> "aa2gg3tt41u" =~ "([a-z]+)[0-9]" :: [[String]]
[["aa2","aa"],["gg3","gg"],["tt4","tt"]]
```

The first element in a list will always be the complete match, followed by the sub-matches. If you're just interested in the complete match, use `map head` or provide your own operator:

```
(?=~) :: String -> String -> [String]
str ?=~ re = map head (str =~ re)
```

Comment: Thanks! Fantastic. Why this is so different from any other language? ```\d+``` used to work in Python, NodeJS, PHP, Go, without particular regard to Posix or whatever.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov Because there is no regex support in the standard library, and the __arbitrary__ package you've used has some quirks. Given it's quirky return type, regex is not used that often.

Comment: Worse than that, while your suggestion works interactively, it won't compile with errors like  ```No instance for (RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source0)
      arising from a use of ‘=~’
    The type variable ‘source0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance RegexMaker
                 Regex
                 CompOption
                 ExecOption
...```

Comment: I have to put something like this ```let m = s =~ ("[0-9]+" :: String) :: [[String]]``` inside a function of my module, to get rid of fatal errors. What is it?

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov, yeah, a general version of `(?=~)` needs several extensions, and I don't have enough insight of `regex-tdfa` to find all sources of this issue. The simpler variant should work though.