# ByteString regex match with AllTextMatches result type

Tags: regex, haskell, ghc

I'm having problems with the following example ghci interaction from Chapter 8 of Real World Haskell. With the help of rampion's answer to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636780/1564106), the expected output should be:

```
> :m +Text.Regex.Posix Data.ByteString.Char8
> getAllTextMatches $ pack "foo" =~ pack "o" :: [(Int, Int)]
[(1,1),(2,1)]
```

instead, I see a missing instance error:

```
> getAllTextMatches $ pack "foo" =~ pack "o" :: [(Int, Int)]
    No instance for (RegexContext
                       Regex ByteString (AllTextMatches [] (Int, Int)))
      arising from a use of `=~'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (RegexContext Regex ByteString (AllTextMatches [] (Int, Int)))
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `pack "foo" =~ pack "o"'
    In the expression:
        getAllTextMatches $ pack "foo" =~ pack "o" :: [(Int, Int)]
    In an equation for `it':
        it = getAllTextMatches $ pack "foo" =~ pack "o" :: [(Int, Int)]
```

what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your error:

```
No instance for (RegexContext
                   Regex ByteString (AllTextMatches [] (Int, Int)))
```

Looking at what we have in scope, `AllTextMatches` only defines one `RegexContext` instance:

```
λ :info AllTextMatches
...
instance RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b (AllTextMatches [] b)
  -- Defined in ‘Text.Regex.Base.Context’
```

And there's only two `RegexLike` instances in scope:

```
λ :i RegexLike
...
instance RegexLike Regex String
  -- Defined in ‘Text.Regex.Posix.String’
instance RegexLike Regex ByteString
  -- Defined in ‘Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString’
```

Since we're dealing with `ByteString`s here, we must be using the `RegexLike Regex ByteString` instance, which lets us infer `a` and `b` in `AllTextMatches`' instance of `RegexContext` as `Regex` and `ByteString`, so we have:

```
RegexContext Regex ByteString (AllTextMatches [] ByteString)
```

If we ask for that:

```
λ getAllTextMatches (pack "foo" =~ pack "o") :: [ByteString]
["o","o"]
```

It works!

But that doesn't give us anything like a `(MatchOffset, MatchLength)`, which is a bit of a bummer.

I'm guessing you're trying [to run this example](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html#regexp.ghci:mix.simple)?

There's considerable discussion in the comments there, but the long and the short of it is that the API for `Text.Regex.Posix` has apparently shifted since RWH was written. Not too surprising since it's now `0.95.2`, and [when RWH was first published in November 2008](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) [the latest version was `0.72.3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.72.0.3).

These days, [to get a list of all the match positions and offsets use `getAllMatches`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base-0.93.2/docs/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v:getAllMatches) instead.

```
λ getAllMatches (pack "foo" =~ pack "o") :: [(Int, Int)]
[(1,1),(2,1)]
```